# Loop through gridview rows and access each row's element by jquery

Tags: jquery

suppose i have gridview and having few rows. each rows have checkbox,textbox,combo in each column. how can i loop through gridview using jquery and access each elements in rows in loop for collection the value at client side by jquery. help me with sample jquery code.

thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a "please write code for me" question. See [Is this question asking for code a good one?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/314472/is-this-question-asking-for-code-a-good-one/314506)

Answer (score 0):

If your elements have unique names you can simply use the serialize function. 
This will create a parameter string like:

> "textbox1=value1&etc" for `<input
>   type="text" name="textbox1"
>   value="value1" />`.

```
var paramString = $('#gridview :input').serialize();
```